# R Is there a way to remove special character from beginning of a string

Tags: r

A field from my dataset has some of it's observations to start with a "." e.g ".TN34AB1336"instead of "TN34AB1336".
I've tried

```
truck_log <- truck_log %>%
  filter(BookingID != "WDSBKTP49392") %>%
  filter(BookingID != "WDSBKTP44502") %>%
  mutate(GpsProvider = str_replace(GpsProvider, "NULL", "UnknownGPS")) %>%
  mutate(vehicle_no = str_replace(vehicle_no, ".TN34AB1336", "TN34AB1336"))
```

the last mutate command in my code worked but there are more of such issues in another field e.g "###TN34AB1336" instead of "TN34AB1336".

So I need a way of automating the process such that all observations that doesn't start with a character is trimmed from the left by a single command in R.

I've attached a picture of a filtered field from spreadsheet to make the question clearer.[image: filtered column showing the issue]

Answer (score 2):

We can use regular expressions to replace anything up to the first alphanumeric character with `""`to remove everything that is not a Number/Character from the beginning of a string:

```
names <- c("###TN34AB1336",
           ".TN34AB1336",
           ",TN654835A34",
           ":+?%TN735345")
stringr::str_replace(names,"^.+?(?=[[:alnum:]])","") # Matches up to, but not including the first alphanumeric character and replaces with ""
[1] "TN34AB1336"  "TN34AB1336"  "TN654835A34" "TN735345"   
``
```

Comment: in case it's useful to the OP, the regex string here is:  `^` (start at the beginning) `.+?` (any character, one or more of them, keep this bit as short as possible) `(?=` (look ahead to the next bit but don't include it in the section to be replaced by ""), `[[:alnum;;]]` (any alphanumeric character) `)` (close the look ahead section).    To phrase it another way, find the first alphanumeric character and select anything from the start of the string, up to but not including that character.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the cold run, but it didn't effect any change on the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`.

```
s <- c(".TN34AB1336", "###TN34AB1336")
sub("^[^A-Z]*", "", s)
#[1] "TN34AB1336" "TN34AB1336"
```

Where `^` is the start of the string, `[^A-Z]` matches everything what is not A, B, C, ... , Z and `*` matches it 0 to n times.